RecordType failed to deploy due to duplicate value found: <unknown>
everyone!
So, I was trying to deploy a new Opportunity Record Type from one Dev sandbox to another (Dev > UAT) using both Change-set and DevOps Center, but I keep receiving the following error with both tools:
Opportunity.Virtual_Opportunity of Type RecordType failed to deploy due to duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>
I read other post, online forums, and different sources for similar errors and followed some suggestions about adding the Page Layout to the package (because it shares Page Layout with another Opportunity Record Type) or deactivating the Field History Track, among other things. But nothing I have tried seems to work.
So far, the components involved in the package are: RecordType, layout and BusinessProcess. Layout Assignment and Layout Permissions do not seemed to be visible on DevOps Center.
Am I missing something?

I am having the same problem :(

if using recordTypes and Sales Processes, make sure those are correct in source and target org

Hi @cropredy! The new recordtype is a variation of an old one, so they share Sales process and layouts.

are you also deploying layout permissions and BusinessProcess?

@cropredy layout permissions is not available/visible on DevOps Center. Same case with layout assignment. I also try deploying the package with the BusinessProcess but didn't work. I'll update the question with involved components.
